# No me impactan los valores matricula, especialidad y servicioactual, en ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
Profesionales p = _context.Profesionales.Where(s => s.Id == profesional.Id).First();

p.Persona = persona;
p.Matricula = profesional.Matricula;
p.Especialidad = _context.Especialidades.Find(profesional.Especialidad.Id);
p.ServicioActual = _context.Servicios.Find(p.Especialidad.Servicios.Id);

_context.SaveChanges();
```

No me estaria guardando matricula, especialidad y servicio actual en la base de datos.

Comment: De donde sale la variable profesional?

Comment: Es un modelo que recibe como parametros, asi (Profesionales profesional), pase la parte que no me funciona del codigo nada mas

Comment: Pon mas codigo que el error puede estar en otra parte

Comment: te podria hablar por discord?

Comment: No explicate mejor por aki y cuando tengas 20 ptos de reputacion  podemos chatear por aki mismo en el chat de stackoverflow

Comment: Y porque no haces  simplemente `_context.Update(profesional);  _context.SaveChanges();` ???

Comment: por qué no muestras mejor como tienes toda esa función

Answer (score 0):

Solamente te falta indicar que hubo cambios.
Agrega esta línea justo antes de guardar cambios:

```
_context.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Modified;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: No creo que tenga q ver con eso